# Javascript - Convert ####-##-## to Epoch time

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to take a date object from a HTML object in the format of `####-##-##` and convert it to epoch time. For example, the user inputs the value of August 12, 2012 which shows as 2012-08-12 when I print out the .val() of it, and I need to get this in Epoch time.

**EDIT**

Code to date:

```
if (hvStartDate == "") {
    hvStartDate = "start"
} 
else {
    console.log($("#hv-start-date").val()); // => 2012-08-20
    hvStartDate = new Date($("#hv-start-date").val()).getTime(); // => NaN
}
if (hvEndDate == "") {
    hvEndDate = "end"
} 
else {
    hvEndDate = new Date($("#hv-end-date").val()).getTime(); // => NaN
}

var myTmp = new Date("2012-08-20");
console.log(myTmp.getTime()); // => NaN
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Javascript's `Date` built-in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) allows you to pass a date string into its constructor, giving you a Date based on that string. From there, calling `getTime( )` will give you the epoch time.

```
new Date($('.user-value').val()).getTime();  // => epoch time
new Date('2012-08-12').getTime();  // 1344729600000
```

Caveat: Beware of locale strings and locale-specific date formatting (for example, the position of days and months switch depending on locale).

EDIT: Based on your code in the comment below, here's what you need to do. Notice that you have to instantiate a new Date Object *before* calling `getTime()`:

```
if (hvStartDate == "") {
    hvStartDate = "start"
} 
else {
    hvStartDate = new Date($("#hv-start-date").val()).getTime();
}
```

Comment: So I have to still be doing something wrong. here's what I have now: 
`if (hvStartDate == "") {hvStartDate = "start"} else {hvStartDate = new Date($("#hv-start-date").val().getTime())}`

Comment: Check the edit above. You'll need to instantiate your Date object first.

Comment: I just get the NaN return value when i do these. I noticed that I had the closing parenthesis in the wrong place (after getTime() instead of after .val()) so I fixed that, but still getting NaN

Comment: What does `$('#hv-start-date').val()` look like?

Comment: `console.log($("#hv-start-date")); // => 2012-08-20` and still getting the Not a Number return value. I editted the code in my first post to show more exactly what's happening.

Answer (score 3):

Simply use the `getTime()` function. It returns the number of milliseconds since Epoch :

```
  var msSinceEpoch = myDate.getTime();
```

Complete Date reference at MDN : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

EDIT : if you have to parse it too, you may :

- use `new Date(theString)` if it has the good format
- set yourself the different date fields (see reference) after having parsed it
- use a date parsing library. I use this one : http://www.datejs.com/ which is very powerful for all date parsing, computing and formating.

Comment: What do you mean? The current time will not always be what the user enters.

Comment: I thougth you already had a Date object. Do you have to parse it ?

Comment: You call this function from a specified date : `inputDate.getTime()`